# Could not import vxlapi: Could not find module 'vxlapi64'

Tags: python, vector, bootloader, can-bus

I'm using this [can bootloader](https://github.com/effenco/stm32-can-bootloader). I get this error and I don't know how to load the driver.

```
Could not import vxlapi: Could not find module 'vxlapi64' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\stm32-can-bootloader\LOADER\PY-CAN-LOADER.py", line 442, in <module>
    bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='vector', app_name='CANalyzer', channel=0, bitrate=500000)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\naomi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\can\interface.py", line 127, in __new__
    bus = cls(channel, *args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\naomi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\can\util.py", line 337, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\naomi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\can\interfaces\vector\canlib.py", line 154, in __init__
    raise CanInterfaceNotImplementedError("The Vector API has not been loaded")
can.exceptions.CanInterfaceNotImplementedError: The Vector API has not been loaded
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing the vxlapi.dll and vxlapi64.dll in the C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and C:\Windows\System32 respectively, its a library missing issue.